# .Net Core app throws null exception when published to web server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've completed my first ever ASP.Net  project and published it to a web server. The project is built on .Net Core as the title suggests. Basically, it's a shift scheduling app. Here is the Shift model:

```
public class Shift
{
    public int ShiftID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Working For:")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:D}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ShiftDate { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID{ get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Additional Information:")]
    public string Information { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ShiftOfficer> ShiftOfficer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ShiftMission> ShiftMission { get; set; }
}
```

When the shift is edited, the only field that can actually be changed via my ViewModel is the `Information` section. `shiftEdit` is the viewmodel argument.

```
 var shiftUpdate = _context.Shifts.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ShiftID == shiftEdit.Shift.ShiftID);
                shiftUpdate.Information = shiftEdit.Shift.Information;
                _context.Shifts.Update(shiftUpdate);
```

This works flawlessly on my development machine using a remote SQL server. However once I published it to a web host, using the same database, I get an error. The logs indicate the `shiftUpdate.Information = shiftEdit.Shift.Information;` is causing a null exception, although the field is nullable on the database.

```
  info:Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommandBuilderFactory[1]
  Executed DbCommand (82ms) [Parameters=[@__shiftEdit_Shift_ShiftID_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT TOP(2) [s].[ShiftID], [s].[Information], [s].[DepartmentID], [s].[ShiftDate]
  FROM [Shifts] AS [s]
  WHERE [s].[ShiftID] = @__shiftEdit_Shift_ShiftID_0
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
  An unhandled exception has occurred: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.at     
MetroBoardCore_v2.Controllers.ShiftController.Edit(Int32 id, ShiftEditViewModel shiftEdit)MetroBoardCore_v2\Controllers\ShiftController.cs:line 335
```

Line 335 in my code is `shiftUpdate.Information = shiftEdit.Shift.Information;` What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Well either `shiftUpdate` is null, or `shiftEdit` is null, or `shiftEdit.Shift` is null. You should find out which. Note that you're using `SingleOrDefault` which suggests you know `shiftUpdate` *might* be null... you should really work out what you want to do if it is.

Comment: I've debugged it over and over on my local machine and all params come back with values. I just can't figure out why the behavior would be different when it's deployed.